# Rhomobile upgrade to 5.1 app build failure

Tags: android, ruby, build, rake

I wonder if anyone can give me a clue where to look on this one.

I am trying to upgrade a RhoMobile application from 2.2 to 5.1.

The driver being the loss of file write permissions in KitKat as part of a camera-callback. I'm looking to move the captured image away from the (volatile) blob storage. Code works okay but not on KitKat.

So I have prepared a new machine with RMS5/Android/Java and then I did an update via search+replace of 'File.' with 'RhoFile.'.

Having repaired the ruby file to use my D: drive installation I'm now getting much further into the build but it's aborting with:

```
.....<br/>
cd d:/RhoMobileSuite5.1.1/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rhodes-5.1.1
rake aborted!
NameError: uninitialized constant Rho::AppManifest::RhoFile

Tasks: TOP => build:android:extensions => config:android:extensions => build:bun
dle:noxruby
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

So I have run with --trace and the end of that is:

```
.....

rm refresh_btn.wp8.png
rm sip_btn.wp8.png
-$TIME$- message [ common_bundle_start() FINISH ] time is { 2015-08-25T14:03:36Z
 } milliseconds from start (372125)
cd Z:/IHS/Projects/RSWorkspace/ECMK_MobileApp/bin/tmp/assets
cd Z:/IHS/Projects/RSWorkspace/ECMK_MobileApp/bin/tmp/assets/apps
cd d:/RhoMobileSuite5.1.1/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rhodes-5.1.1
rake aborted!
NameError: uninitialized constant Rho::AppManifest::RhoFile
d:/RhoMobileSuite5.1.1/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rhodes-5.1.1/lib/framework/
rhoappmanifest.rb:39:in `block in enumerate_models'
d:/RhoMobileSuite5.1.1/ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/find.rb:41:in `block in find'
d:/RhoMobileSuite5.1.1/ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/find.rb:40:in `catch'
d:/RhoMobileSuite5.1.1/ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/find.rb:40:in `find'
d:/RhoMobileSuite5.1.1/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rhodes-5.1.1/lib/framework/
rhoappmanifest.rb:37:in `enumerate_models'
d:/RhoMobileSuite5.1.1/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rhodes-5.1.1/Rakefile:3784:
in `create_manifest'
d:/RhoMobileSuite5.1.1/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rhodes-5.1.1/Rakefile:4023:
in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
d:/RhoMobileSuite5.1.1/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.r
b:240:in `call'
d:/RhoMobileSuite5.1.1/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.r
b:240:in `block in execute'
d:/RhoMobileSuite5.1.1/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.r
b:235:in `each'
d:/RhoMobileSuite5.1.1/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.r
b:235:in `execute'
d:/RhoMobileSuite5.1.1/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.r
b:179:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
d:/RhoMobileSuite5.1.1/ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
d:/RhoMobileSuite5.1.1/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.r
b:172:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
d:/RhoMobileSuite5.1.1/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.r
b:201:in `block in invoke_prerequisites'
d:/RhoMobileSuite5.1.1/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.r
b:199:in `each'
d:/RhoMobileSuite5.1.1/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.r
b:199:in `invoke_prerequisites'
d:/RhoMobileSuite5.1.1/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.r
b:178:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
d:/RhoMobileSuite5.1.1/ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
d:/RhoMobileSuite5.1.1/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.r
b:172:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
d:/RhoMobileSuite5.1.1/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.r
b:201:in `block in invoke_prerequisites'
d:/RhoMobileSuite5.1.1/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.r
b:199:in `each'
d:/RhoMobileSuite5.1.1/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.r
b:199:in `invoke_prerequisites'
d:/RhoMobileSuite5.1.1/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.r
b:178:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
d:/RhoMobileSuite5.1.1/ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
d:/RhoMobileSuite5.1.1/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.r
b:172:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
d:/RhoMobileSuite5.1.1/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.r
b:165:in `invoke'
d:/RhoMobileSuite5.1.1/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rhodes-5.1.1/Rakefile:4999:
in `invoke'
d:/RhoMobileSuite5.1.1/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rhodes-5.1.1/platform/andro
id/build/android.rake:866:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
d:/RhoMobileSuite5.1.1/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.r
b:240:in `call'
d:/RhoMobileSuite5.1.1/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.r
b:240:in `block in execute'
d:/RhoMobileSuite5.1.1/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.r
b:235:in `each'
d:/RhoMobileSuite5.1.1/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.r
b:235:in `execute'
d:/RhoMobileSuite5.1.1/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.r
b:179:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
d:/RhoMobileSuite5.1.1/ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
d:/RhoMobileSuite5.1.1/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.r
b:172:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
d:/RhoMobileSuite5.1.1/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.r
b:201:in `block in invoke_prerequisites'
d:/RhoMobileSuite5.1.1/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.r
b:199:in `each'
d:/RhoMobileSuite5.1.1/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.r
b:199:in `invoke_prerequisites'
d:/RhoMobileSuite5.1.1/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.r
b:178:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
d:/RhoMobileSuite5.1.1/ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
d:/RhoMobileSuite5.1.1/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.r
b:172:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
d:/RhoMobileSuite5.1.1/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.r
b:201:in `block in invoke_prerequisites'
d:/RhoMobileSuite5.1.1/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.r
b:199:in `each'
d:/RhoMobileSuite5.1.1/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.r
b:199:in `invoke_prerequisites'
d:/RhoMobileSuite5.1.1/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.r
b:178:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
d:/RhoMobileSuite5.1.1/ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
d:/RhoMobileSuite5.1.1/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.r
b:172:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
d:/RhoMobileSuite5.1.1/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.r
b:201:in `block in invoke_prerequisites'
d:/RhoMobileSuite5.1.1/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.r
b:199:in `each'
d:/RhoMobileSuite5.1.1/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.r
b:199:in `invoke_prerequisites'
d:/RhoMobileSuite5.1.1/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.r
b:178:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
d:/RhoMobileSuite5.1.1/ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
d:/RhoMobileSuite5.1.1/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.r
b:172:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
d:/RhoMobileSuite5.1.1/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.r
b:165:in `invoke'
d:/RhoMobileSuite5.1.1/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rhodes-5.1.1/Rakefile:4999:
in `invoke'
d:/RhoMobileSuite5.1.1/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/applic
ation.rb:150:in `invoke_task'
d:/RhoMobileSuite5.1.1/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/applic
ation.rb:106:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
d:/RhoMobileSuite5.1.1/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/applic
ation.rb:106:in `each'
d:/RhoMobileSuite5.1.1/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/applic
ation.rb:106:in `block in top_level'
d:/RhoMobileSuite5.1.1/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/applic
ation.rb:115:in `run_with_threads'
d:/RhoMobileSuite5.1.1/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/applic
ation.rb:100:in `top_level'
d:/RhoMobileSuite5.1.1/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/applic
ation.rb:78:in `block in run'
d:/RhoMobileSuite5.1.1/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/applic
ation.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
d:/RhoMobileSuite5.1.1/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/applic
ation.rb:75:in `run'
d:/RhoMobileSuite5.1.1/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.4.2/bin/rake:33:in
`<top (required)>'
d:/RhoMobileSuite5.1.1/ruby/bin/rake:23:in `load'
d:/RhoMobileSuite5.1.1/ruby/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => build:android:extensions => config:android:extensions => build:bun
dle:noxruby
```

But despite numerous searches I cannot find 'Rho::AppManifest::RhoFile' anywhere within the app/workspace.

Using $ rake device:android:debug.

This is not a corner of my chosing and right now I'm out of ideas.
Thanks in advance to anyone who can help.